# How to avoid cross-reading between different directories under the same domain?

Tags: php, cookies

How to avoid cross-reading between different directories  under the same domain?
For example,

```
setcookie('username', $username, strtotime('+1 months'), '/jp/', '.localdomain.com');
setcookie('username', $username, strtotime('+1 months'), '/cn/', '.localdomain.com');
```

When I use `$_COOKIE['username']` to read the value under

> /jp/

or

> /cn/

respectively?
I am using PHP.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cross-reading"? Do you need to set cookies per language path?

Comment: For example, I want to read the cookie value under /jp/, not /cn/, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain a number of different sessions on the same domain, you need to adjust your [**session cookie parameters**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). It's like the cookie parameters but specifically for the session cookie.

Comment: Sorry,I mean cookie, not session.

Comment: When I apply $_COOKIE['username'], it simply reads cookie value on localdomain.com. It doesn't care about the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cookie path, that cookie should apply to the path and its subdirectories only. I can see nothing in the [manual](http://de.php.net/setcookie) that says otherwise, and if there are known problems with a function they most often are mentioned in the User Contributed Notes.

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

- Can you confirm 100% that a cookie value set for /jp/ is available in /cn/?
- Could it be that you have an older cookie from an earlier attempt that is valid for the whole domain?
- You could try setting the cookie explicitly in /jp/index.php and /cn/index.php and see whether they still interfere. The `$path` argument should make this unnecessary but it's always worth a try.

Anyway, I'll bet a beer there's a old cookie somewhere or something like that.